# Socket.io reading and writing binary data with zero copy buffers

Tags: node.js, linux, websocket, socket.io

I see that socket.io supports binary data. To send I could just set a Buffer object.
I want to send / receive a large number medium size files. I want to see if it can be optimized. When creating a Buffer from file and sending via socket.io, does it internally create any copy is the data or is it handled with zero-copy?

Similarly, when receiving, is it possible to receive the data as a Buffer that can be written to a file without creating a copy? I couldn't find an example of receiving data as a Buffer. Can someone point out examples of receiving binary data as a Buffer?

Comment: you can send file by chunks, create a stream and write them to the file

Comment: It still copies the contents explicitly. I want to have a zero-copy solution. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy